# sorting divs by date

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html. There are some options. Each of them has elements p: date and name. I need to sort these divs by date via p "date". Ignore the p with names

```
<div id="divs">
    <div class="option">
        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o date"></i>12.10.2018 12:05</small>
        <p class="name">Jones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o date"></i>12.11.2015 02:25</small>
        <p class="name">Micheal</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o date"></i>02.11.2020 21:50</small>
        <p class="name">Micheal</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to sort divs by date in class "date". I tried this script

```
var listitems = document.querySelectorAll('#option > date');

listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return    $(b).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(a).text().toUpperCase());
});

$.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
   mylist.append(item); 
});
```

Comment: what's your end goal? to write a script after checking date/\?

Comment: It's usually easier to sort your data before generating the html (assuming it's not hard coded) - If you start from the html you have to work backward and parse it into js objects that can be manipulated

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#option > date')` - There's no element with the id `option`. If you fix it to be a class selector then it won't match anything either because there is no `<date>` element. If you fix this also it still won't match anything because the elements with a `date` class are no direct childs of an `option`. And even if this would be the case the `<i>` elements have no content (date) hence there's nothing to compare. -> Long story short: read up on css selectors

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, it's relatively easy.

1. Create a jQuery object of arrays representing the `<small>` tags of each `.option`. Your original `date` selector doesn't have a tag in your html. The actual date is within the `<small>` tag.
2. Call the `sort` function on this array using a custom compare function. This sorts in ascending order, to change it do descending switch the `>` sign to `<`.
3. Just print out the values.

```js
// Detach the DOM elements
var listitems = $('#divs').detach('.option'); 
var children = listitems.children();

// Sort directly with the DOM elements
children.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date($(a).children().first().text() > $(b).children().first().text());
});

// Remove 'old' DOM elements
listitems.empty();
// Append 'new' DOM elements
listitems.append(children);
// Append list back to <body>
$('body').append(listitems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divs">
    <div class="option">
        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o date"></i>12.10.2018 12:05</small>
        <p class="name">Jones</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o date"></i>12.11.2015 02:25</small>
        <p class="name">Micheal</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o date"></i>02.11.2020 21:50</small>
        <p class="name">Micheal</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just to clarify, use `.class` selectors to select a class and `#id` selectors to select ids, and just use `tag` selectors when selecting tags.

You were trying to select the `#option`, but `option` is a class in your html. Also, you were trying to select all the `date` tags within the `#option` id. There are no `<date>` tags in your html. The actual date is just text that is within the `<small>` tags. `<small ...><i ...></i>02.11.2020 21:50</small>`

Read more about selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

I strongly advise you to read more about the DOM [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

Comment: how to append to html not to console?